# Send email based on the value of a column?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two sheet 1. SS & 2. MessageOutput.

On first time run, email is sucessfully send. But for second time run, we get error:

> Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1

This is on the line: `var messageRange = messagesheet.getRange(1, 1, mailMessage.length, 5);`

Here is the code:

```
function sendEmail() {

  //setup spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var datasheetname = "SS";
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName(datasheetname);
  var messagesheetname = "MessageOutput";
  var messagesheet = ss.getSheetByName(messagesheetname);
  var templatesheetname = "Email Template";
  var templatesheet = ss.getSheetByName(templatesheetname);  
  messagesheet.clear();

  // get the number of rows on the data sheet
  var Avals = datasheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
  //Logger.log("Alast = "+Alast);
  var sslast = datasheet.getLastRow();

  // get the supplier column
  var supplierRange = datasheet.getRange(3,7,Alast-2,1);

  //get the supplier data
  var supplierData = supplierRange.getValues();

  //get the status column
  var statusRange = datasheet.getRange(3,9,Alast-2,1);

  // get the status data
  var statusData = statusRange.getValues();

  var transCount = supplierData.length;
  var supplierList = [];
  var transData = datasheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // supplierList contains the unique supplier list
  supplierData.forEach(function(x){
    if(supplierList.indexOf(x[0]) === -1 && x[0]!="" ){
        supplierList.push(x[0]);
    }                   
  });
  var supplierCount = supplierList.length;


  var itemCount = 0;
  var mailMessage = [];
  var mailItem = [];

  //build the mail item header
  var mailItemHeader = [];
  mailItemHeader.push(transData[0][0]);
  mailItemHeader.push(transData[0][1]);
  mailItemHeader.push(transData[0][2]);
  mailItemHeader.push(transData[0][3]);
  mailItemHeader.push(transData[0][4]);
  //mailItemHeader.push(transData[0][6]);

   // loop through the data, once for every supplier
  for (supplier = 0; supplier<supplierCount; supplier++){
    mailMessage=[];
    itemCount = 0;

    // now loop through the data
    // start i = 2 to allow for header
    for (var i = 2; i < transCount+2; i++) {
      mailItem=[];

    // the suplier matches and if the checkbox is false
     if (supplierList[supplier] == transData[i][6] && transData[i][8] == false){

        // this this is the first item then push the mail header 
        if (itemCount ==0){
          mailMessage.push(mailItemHeader);
          // get the email address
          var emailAddress = transData[i][5];
          var subject = "Purchase order";
        }

        // this is a match
        var emailAddress = transData[i][5];

       // push the transation values for this row onto the mailitem array
        mailItem.push(transData[i][0]);
        mailItem.push(transData[i][1]);
        mailItem.push(transData[i][2]);
        mailItem.push(transData[i][3]);
        mailItem.push(transData[i][4]);
       //mailItem.push(transData[i][6]);

      // push the row onto the rest of the mail message data
        mailMessage.push(mailItem);
        itemCount=itemCount+1

        //update the status value to true
        statusData[i-2] = [true];
      }
      else
      {
      //Logger.log("no match");
      }

    } // end of the transaction loop for this supplier

    // define the temporary output range
    var messageRange = messagesheet.getRange(1, 1, mailMessage.length, 5);
    // paste the items details to the temporary output range
    var messageupdate = messageRange.setValues(mailMessage);

    // get the values for the items only (no header)
    var messagedata = messagesheet.getRange(2, 1, mailMessage.length-1, 5).getValues();
    var messageitemcount = messagedata.length;

    // create a subject
    var emailSubject = "Purchase Order: StackOverflow Test";
    // get the email address
    var emailaddress = emailAddress;

    // message
    var messagePrefix = "Attention: "+supplierList[supplier];

    // start the build of the html message
    var columns = 5;
    var columncount=1;
    var message = 'Please supply the following products:<br><br><table style="border-collapse:collapse;" border = 1 cellpadding = 5>';
    // get the headers
    for (h=0; h<columns;h++){

      if (columncount ==1){
        var header = '<tr>';
      }

      header+='<th style="background-color:#ffeb3b">'+mailItemHeader[h]+'</th>';

      if (columncount ==5){
        header+='</tr>';
      }
      columncount=columncount+1
    }

    // add the header to the mesage
    message+=header;

    // loop through the items on the temporary output and get the item values
    for(c=0;c<messageitemcount;c++){

      // increment message
      message+='<tr><td>'+messagedata[c][0]+'</td>'+'<td>'+messagedata[c][1]+'</td>'+'<td>'+messagedata[c][2]+'</td>'+'<td>'+messagedata[c][3]+'</td>'+'<td>'+messagedata[c][4]+'</td></tr>';

    }

    // finalise the message
    message+='</table>';  

    // send the email
    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailaddress, emailSubject,  messagePrefix, {htmlBody: message,  });

    // clear the state from the temporary outsheet sheet
    messagesheet.clear();

  }
  //update the status range - return all to ticked (true)
  statusRange.setValues(statusData);

}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

> Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1

indicates that

`mailMessage.length`

in

`var messageRange = messagesheet.getRange(1, 1, mailMessage.length, 5);`

is `0`.

You can catch this case with the `if` statement, e.g.:

```
if(mailMessage.length>0){
    var messageRange = messagesheet.getRange(1, 1, mailMessage.length, 5);
    // paste the items details to the temporary output range
    var messageupdate = messageRange.setValues(mailMessage);
    ...
    //the rest of your code that should be run only if mailMessage is not empty
   GmailApp.sendEmail(emailaddress, emailSubject,  messagePrefix, {htmlBody: message,  });
   ...
}
...
```

Note, you might want to review your code and understand why `mailMessage.length` is 0.
It seems like you only assign it values to `mailMessage`, when

`if (supplierList[supplier] == transData[i][6] && transData[i][8] == false)`,

so you can put the rest of the message sending related code within the same statement.

Comment: Hi, as u told i tried, but it's going to long waiting loop.                                                                       Here is my SS sheet Header:                                                                                     Item Name | Spec | Colour | Qty | Unit | MailID | Vendor | Remarks | Status

Comment: If you want me to have a look at your data, you should provide your (sanitized) spreadsheet rather than jsut the headers - because the problem probably is that some of your rows have empty entries.

Comment: Hi, My concern is only send email against unique "Vendor Code" & mark "True" AND 2. when i run next time check for new row where "Status is NIL". Here is the link of my Spreadsheet -- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GMsacufEeWbO0eXxHYcOIwJFRAZTs4AqDTrpa_yx9V0/edit#gid=0

Comment: Please provide public viewing permission.

Comment: I checked your sheet and code and can verify that if you implement `if(mailMessage.length>0)` as I recommended you, it will work as intended and only attempt to send emails then `mailMessage` is not empty. There is no long waiting loop. However, you hsve other issue in your code. For example, you do not set your coutner variables correctly for iteration.  Keep in mind that the first array element is always 0, not 1 and if you define `i < transCount+2;` you will attempt to iterate through more rows that exist, which will give you an error. You also retrieve `statusRange` incorrectly.